# JSON Array and simple data in the same column

Tags: mysql, json

I work on a mySQL db with a column consisted of simple data and JSON array. How should i implement the SELECT to retrieve the values ?? Check the screenshot

[image: here]

Comment: If you need to allow multiple phone numbers, you should normalize it. Make another table of phone numbers, with a foreign key to this table.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I didn't mixed them... This db is already implemented like this. Somehow i must retrieve the values with SQL query .

Comment: Check if the value contains `[`. If it does, use `JSON_SEARCH()` to search for the value you want, otherwise use `=`.

Comment: `SELECT` is a relational command. Your data is not relational so you are going to have enormous problems every time you try to use it. You need to convert your data to [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you dont give enough information, i suppose you at least have a corresponding table and you can get the row id of the phone that you want to pull. With that in mind

```
--also assuming that the table is called phones
SELECT * FROM PHONES;
SET @result := (SELECT phone FROM PHONES WHERE Id = 2);
SELECT IF(JSON_VALID(@result) = 1, json_extract(@result,'$[0]'), @result) AS Result;
```

What this does is that it checks if the entry is valid json, and if it does it extracts the first phone number. if its not, then it returns the original result.

if you want to return all phone numbers then an additional query is needed to find how long is that json array

```
json_array_length('[1,2]') → 2
```

Then the `CONCAT` function to concatenate the phone numbers, using a comma or something